# VBA function returns to calling routine on an assignment statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a mid-level function that is called and calls other functions.  Inside the function a dynamic arrary is "Dim myarrary() As Variant" is loaded from called function. The arrary "myarrary" is loaded with the proper data.  When I attempt to assign the arrary to range

```
Dim datarng as Range

datarng = WorkSheets("DATA").Range("A1:H3700").Value
```

The debugger executes the statement and immediately returns to the top level routine that initiated the process.  I'm thinking I crashed the stack somehow but I've place strings around myarray and they are intact.  if I comment out the assignment statement the routine executes the remaining code in the function.

Comment: It sounds to me like your code is raising an error. That will stop the execution of that function if you have no error handler. Then Excel might be calling your top level function again from a different cell. It's hard to say without more details. See these links for some possibly helpful information, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861431/vba-how-to-get-the-last-used-cell-by-vba-code-when-the-last-error-occured-in-a-w/3874340#3874340 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379882/excel-vba-formula-called-from-a-cell-stops-processing-vba-or-encounters-an-app/4380316#4380316

Comment: Your are correct.  Once I created an error handler I discovered that problem was the assignment of my myarray to my range object.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you have an error handler in the top-level routine but not in the lower-level functions.  In that type of situation, when the code hits a run-time error it steps immediately to the routine that had an error handler.

Also, Dim myarrary() As Variant creates an array of variants, which I don't think is what you want.  It looks like you just want a variant, like:

```
Dim myarrary As Variant
```

You can then assign a range to it, e.g.:

```
myarrary = WorkSheets("DATA").Range("A1:H3700").Value
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example code will not compile for two reasons:

```
Dim datarng as Range
datarng = WorkSheets("DATA").Range("A1:H3700").Value
```

1. You can't assign a "value" to a Range. Right hand side should be `WorkSheets("DATA").Range("A1:H3700")`, and not `WorkSheets("DATA").Range("A1:H3700").Value`.
2. `datarng` is an object (of type `Range`), so you need the `Set` keyword to make the assignment. Left hand side should be `Set datarng`.

The correct syntax is therefore:

```
Set datarng = WorkSheets("DATA").Range("A1:H3700")
```

Of course you can also dump the value content of `datarng` into a Variant like this:

```
Dim myArray as Variant
myArray = datarng ' or datarng.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `Set` in front of `datarng = WorkSheets("DATA").Range("A1:H3700").Value`

should be `Set datarng = WorkSheets("DATA").Range("A1:H3700")`

Comment: Yup!  that solved the assignment problem but when I assign myarray to datarng I trigger my error handler now.

Comment: @Charles Williams: But that won't compile either! (At least not on my Excel 2003...)

Comment: If datarng is a Range, one should use SET, but without `.Value` then !!

Comment: Thanks guys, had not spotted the .value on the end: now fixed